# T-SQL: Reduce query load when getting multilevel product categories

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm storing the categories to whichs products in `[products]` are assigned in `[products_category_mapping]`.
A product can be assigned to a category in level 0, 1 and 2. So a product will occur in `[products_category_mapping]` either 1, 2 or 3 times depending on to which levels the product is assigned.

Then I want to retrieve via a query the data on the categories to which those products belong.
These queries are quite expensive since they contain a lot of joins and we need to check for each category level whether the product occurs for that level. Also there around 200.000 products, each assigned to 1,2 or 3 categories, so it takes a very long time to run the queries below.

**My question: how can I optimize the performance of these queries?**

ps. please refrain from suggesting a table redesign, seeing where we are in the process, that is not viable right now.

Current queries:

```
SELECT label_nl+';'+slug_nl as labelslug_nl_0,label_en+';'+slug_en as labelslug_en_0,label_nl as label_nl_0,label_en as label_en_0,slug_nl as slug_nl_0,slug_en as slug_en_0
,pagetitle_nl as pagetitle_nl_0,pagetitle_en as pagetitle_en_0,image_nl as image_nl_0,image_en as image_en_0
,description_nl as description_nl_0,description_en as description_en_0
,metadescription_nl as metadescription_nl_0,metadescription_en as metadescription_en_0 
FROM articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id
INNER JOIN products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid
WHERE gp.id=3216743 AND ga.catlevel=0

SELECT label_nl+';'+slug_nl as labelslug_nl_0,label_en+';'+slug_en as labelslug_en_0,label_nl as label_nl_0,label_en as label_en_0,slug_nl as slug_nl_0,slug_en as slug_en_0
,pagetitle_nl as pagetitle_nl_0,pagetitle_en as pagetitle_en_0,image_nl as image_nl_0,image_en as image_en_0
,description_nl as description_nl_0,description_en as description_en_0
,metadescription_nl as metadescription_nl_0,metadescription_en as metadescription_en_0 
FROM articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id
INNER JOIN products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid
WHERE gp.id=3216743 AND ga.catlevel=1   

SELECT label_nl+';'+slug_nl as labelslug_nl_2,label_en+';'+slug_en as labelslug_en_2,label_nl as label_nl_2,label_en as label_en_2,slug_nl as slug_nl_2,slug_en as slug_en_2
,pagetitle_nl as pagetitle_nl_2,pagetitle_en as pagetitle_en_2,image_nl as image_nl_2,image_en as image_en_2
,description_nl as description_nl_2,description_en as description_en_2
,metadescription_nl as metadescription_nl_2,metadescription_en as metadescription_en_2 
FROM articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id
INNER JOIN products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid
WHERE gp.id=3216743 AND ga.catlevel=2
```

DDL

```
USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[articlegroups]    Script Date: 29-04-2017 18:34:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[articlegroups](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [parentid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [catlevel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [label_nl] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [label_en] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [slug_nl] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [slug_en] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [pagetitle_nl] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [pagetitle_en] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [image_nl] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [image_en] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [description_nl] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [description_en] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [metadescription_nl] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [metadescription_en] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [canonicalurl_nl] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [canonicalurl_en] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_articlegroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[articlegroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_articlegroups_lvl0_catlevel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [catlevel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[articlegroups] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_articlegroups_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO





USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[products_category_mapping]    Script Date: 29-04-2017 18:33:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping](
    [artikelid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [articlegroup_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_products_category_mapping_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_articlegroups_lvl1_mapping_products] FOREIGN KEY([artikelid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[products] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_articlegroups_lvl1_mapping_products]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_products_category_mapping_articlegroups] FOREIGN KEY([articlegroup_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[articlegroups] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[products_category_mapping] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_products_category_mapping_articlegroups]
GO





USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[products]    Script Date: 29-04-2017 18:33:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [friendlyurl] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO






USE [mydb]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[articlegroups] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[articlegroups] ([id], [parentid], [catlevel], [label_nl], [label_en], [slug_nl], [slug_en], [pagetitle_nl], [pagetitle_en], [image_nl], [image_en], [description_nl], [description_en], [metadescription_nl], [metadescription_en], [createdate], [canonicalurl_nl], [canonicalurl_en]) VALUES (129, 0, 0, N'Baby / Geboorte', N'Baby and birth', N'baby-en-geboorte', N'baby-and-birth', N'Baby- en geboorte producten online kopen', N'Baby and birth', N'', N'', N'Alle baby en geboorte artikelen in 1 overzicht. Van kinderwagens tot baby-monitors tot commodes tot de inrichting van de kraamkamer.', N'', N'Online baby en geboorte producten kopen kan hier. Goedkope producten die jou helpen wanneer je net een  baby hebt!', N'', CAST(N'2016-04-12T23:31:43.003' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[articlegroups] ([id], [parentid], [catlevel], [label_nl], [label_en], [slug_nl], [slug_en], [pagetitle_nl], [pagetitle_en], [image_nl], [image_en], [description_nl], [description_en], [metadescription_nl], [metadescription_en], [createdate], [canonicalurl_nl], [canonicalurl_en]) VALUES (680, 129, 1, N'Geboortekaartjes', N'Birth announcement', N'geboorte-kaartjes', N'birth-announcement-cards', N'Baby & Geboortekaartjes bestellen, drukken en versturen', N'Birth Announcements & Baby Birth Announcement Cards', N'', N'', N'Baby & geboortekaartjes bestel je in onze webshop. Wij hebben een flink aanbod in mooie en leuke kaartjes voor baby en geboorte. Schattige kaartjes bestellen.', N'', N'Leuke kaartjes voor baby & geboorte kun je hier eenvoudig bestellen. Originele en leuke kaarten speciaal voor de kleintjes.', N'', CAST(N'2016-04-12T23:31:43.310' AS DateTime), NULL, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[articlegroups] OFF
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[products] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[products] ([id],[friendlyurl]) VALUES (3216743, N'birth-with-flowers')




INSERT [dbo].[products_category_mapping] ([artikelid], [articlegroup_id], [createdate]) VALUES (3216743, 129, CAST(N'2017-04-24T20:05:58.463' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[products_category_mapping] ([artikelid], [articlegroup_id], [createdate]) VALUES (3216743, 680, CAST(N'2017-04-24T20:05:58.463' AS DateTime))
GO
```

** UPDATE 1 **

As per suggestion of @HABO below in comments, I tried using a case statement to combine the 3 queries:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    when ga.catlevel=0 THEN
         label_nl+';'+slug_nl as labelslug_nl_0,label_en+';'+slug_en as labelslug_en_0,label_nl as label_nl_0,label_en as label_en_0,slug_nl as slug_nl_0,slug_en as slug_en_0
        ,pagetitle_nl as pagetitle_nl_0,pagetitle_en as pagetitle_en_0,image_nl as image_nl_0,image_en as image_en_0
        ,description_nl as description_nl_0,description_en as description_en_0
        ,metadescription_nl as metadescription_nl_0,metadescription_en as metadescription_en_0 
    when ga.catlevel=1 THEN
         label_nl+';'+slug_nl as labelslug_nl_1,label_en+';'+slug_en as labelslug_en_1,label_nl as label_nl_1,label_en as label_en_1,slug_nl as slug_nl_1,slug_en as slug_en_1
        ,pagetitle_nl as pagetitle_nl_1,pagetitle_en as pagetitle_en_1,image_nl as image_nl_1,image_en as image_en_1
        ,description_nl as description_nl_1,description_en as description_en_1
        ,metadescription_nl as metadescription_nl_1,metadescription_en as metadescription_en_1 
    else null
END
FROM globos_articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN globos_products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id
INNER JOIN globos_products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid
WHERE gp.id=3216743 AND ga.catlevel in (0,1,2)
```

It's however not clear to me yet, how I can make sure how I can differentiate the columns based on the cat levels: 0,1 or 2

**UPDATE 2**

I get the desired resultset, but it has multiple rows that I want to merge into a single row. When there are multiple rows, each column always has a maximim of 1 value with the other values being `NULL`. I want to merge the multiple rows into a single row where the highest value per column (i.e. not `NULL`) will remain.

**Current resultset**

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>labelslug_nl_0
        </th>
        <th>labelslug_nl_1
        </th>
        <th>labelslug_nl_2
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Baby / Geboorte;baby-en-geboorte
        </td>
        <td>NULL
        </td>
        <td>NULL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>NULL
        </td>
        <td>Geboortekaartjes;geboorte-kaartjes
        </td>
        <td>NULL
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Desired resultset**

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>labelslug_nl_0
        </th>
        <th>labelslug_nl_1
        </th>
        <th>labelslug_nl_2
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Baby / Geboorte;baby-en-geboorte
        </td>
        <td>Geboortekaartjes;geboorte-kaartjes
        </td>
        <td>NULL
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please provide precise metrics for _optimize_. I'd hate to spend time reducing the I/O load when you only care about the memory footprint or minimizing contention. No indexes in your DDL?

Comment: Good point. Actually my query execution takes a long time. I'm guessing that's because I have 3 separate statements with each of them having a lot of joins. I was wondering if perhaps I could combine these 3 statements into a single more efficient one. I have a clustered index on products.id, what others would you recommend? Does that help?

Comment: There don't appear to be "a lot of joins" unless you are using views that are hiding some joins. (I did exceed the maximum number of joined tables in a query in an old project. If memory serves, it was only 512.) Joining on an indexed column is generally faster, i.e. indexing `products.id` (which you have), `products_category_mapping.artikelid`, `products_category_mapping.articlegroup_id` and `articlegroups.id`. An index on `articlegroups` containing `id` and `catlevel` (in that order) would likely help due to the `where` clause. Check the actual execution plan to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: The DDl for the Products table is missing a number of columns, like [artikelnummer], [titel] etc

Comment: @Flo If you want to combine the 3 queries into one you will get only one result set. Your current SELECT statements have 3 result sets each with different column aliases. Does your application need those column aliases to differentiate the separate category data?

Comment: @ChrisAlbert yes, it does need the column aliases...is it still possible then?

Comment: You can combine the queries with different columns thusly: `select expression as labelslug_nl_0, null as labelslug_nl_1, null as labelslug_nl_2, ... union all select null, expression, null, ... union all select null, null, expression, ...`. The first query contains all of the columns needed by all of the queries with nulls in appropriate places. Subsequent queries fill in inapplicable columns with nulls.

Comment: @HABO Thank you. But when I use UNION statement I STILL need to lookup the products.id value 3 times, like I have right now...correct? How would there be a performance improvement?

Comment: Using `union` won't help performance, it was just a way to combine the results with differing columns into a single result set. If I'm squinting correctly, the `from` clauses in all three queries are the same except for the `catlevel` values. That means you could use a single query with `and ga.catlevel in ( 1, 2, 3 )` to get all of the rows and `case` expressions to handle the differences, e.g. `case when ga.catlevel = 1 then label_nl+';'+slug_nl end as labelslug_nl_0, ...`. The default value for a `case` with no `else` is `null`.

Comment: @HABO: You're correct, the queries only differ on the `catlevel` values. cool, it feels like the `case` statement could be a performance optimizing solution, however as you can see in my update 1, it's not clear to me exactly how you envisioned using it in such a way that allows me to distinguish the column names. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single query will retrieve all of the rows that your three queries returned. `CatLevel` `0` and `1` rows will populate the first set of columns and leave the second set filled with nulls. `CatLevel` `2` rows will do the opposite.

```
select
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then label_nl + ';' + slug_nl end as labelslug_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then label_en + ';' + slug_en as labelslug_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then label_nl end as label_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then label_en end as label_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then slug_nl end as slug_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then slug_en end as slug_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then pagetitle_nl end as pagetitle_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then pagetitle_en end as pagetitle_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then image_nl end as image_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then image_en end as image_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then description_nl end as description_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then description_en end as description_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then metadescription_nl end as metadescription_nl_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then metadescription_en end as metadescription_en_0,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then label_nl + ';' + slug_nl end as labelslug_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then label_en + ';' + slug_en as labelslug_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then label_nl end as label_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then label_en end as label_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then slug_nl end as slug_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then slug_en end as slug_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then pagetitle_nl end as pagetitle_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then pagetitle_en end as pagetitle_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then image_nl end as image_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then image_en end as image_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then description_nl end as description_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then description_en end as description_en_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then metadescription_nl end as metadescription_nl_2,
  case when AG.CatLevel = 2 then metadescription_en end as metadescription_en_2
  from ArticleGroups as AG inner join
    Products_Category_Mapping as PCM on PCM.ArticleGroup_Id = AG.Id inner join
    Products as P on P.Id = PCM.ArtikelId
  where P.Id = 3216743 and AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1, 2 )
```

Note that all of the columns referenced should include aliases, e.g. `AG.Label_NL`. This is left as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: I go this to work! Sweet. Just one thing, the resultset now still has as many rows as that catlevels are found, e.g. when only catlevel=0 is found, the resultset has 1 row, when catlevel 0, 1, and 2 are found, it has 3 rows. Is there a way to merge the resultset into a single row? Where `NULL` values are overwritten if another row in the resultset in that same column does contain a value? I'm thinking of using `MAX` somehow in your query, but not sure how. I hope I explained myself clearly there :)

Comment: You should be getting all of the rows that your three queries would have returned. To combine rows you'll need to explain how they are grouped. It may be a matter of using aggregation, i.e. `max` and `group by`, or using `coalesce` to combine values from multiple rows. Sample data and desired results should help clarify things.

Comment: See my Update 2. I've left out most columns for readability. Thanks!

Comment: This may come as a shock, but HTML is not the most readable way to show sample data. And there is still no indication of how rows might be grouped. It appears that you simply want to apply `max` to each column and get one row returned. Easy enough, eh? `select max( case when AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 ) then label_nl + ';' + slug_nl end ) as labelslug_nl_0, ...`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I could not find how to apply a decent table markup in a SO post. And the `MAX` on a `case` like your example does not work for me, since I ended up having to split your `AG.CatLevel in ( 0, 1 )` into `AG.CatLevel = 0` and `AG.CatLevel = 1` respectively to get distinct columns for each of the 3 category levels. What I ended up doing is wrapping your whole statement into a subquery and then apply `MAX` on every column that resultset. That gives me what I need. Thanks! :)